Nexus Repository: Access through Group Repository, Permissions on Hosted Repository
I'm using Sonatype Nexus Repo 3.70 and a little bit confused about Permissions in group vs. hosted repositories.
Is it even possible to set permissions only to the hosted repos but access artifacts over the the group repo?
Following situation: I have 2 hosted docker repositories

docker-products     (restricted access)
docker-oss (public available)

And a group docker repository

docker (reachable as https://docker.example.com) including both hosted repos

Now I created privileges

priv-products: Browse/Read on docker-products
priv-oss: Browse/Read on docker-oss
priv-docker:  Browse/Read on docker group repo

And assigned the priv-oss to anonymous and priv-products to a user-account
My idea was to have the group repo as main entry point (only a single docker login docker.example.com should be necessary).
If I'm checking the Artifacts (UI) as anonymous user, I see only the oss repo? => So i assigned the priv-docker also to anonymous
Now I see both, but the docker repo contains images from products too (the restricted one) => Bad. Has anyone maybe an idea if how I need to adapt the permissions?

See here, I think this is what you're looking for:  https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/24581189750035-How-to-create-private-repositories-in-Nexus-Repository-3

thanks for the link. so it seems its not possible to (easily) have different permissions/views with a single group repository exposed under one url :-/
